# How do I add new pages/extend buddypress components

Tags: php, templates, url, slug, buddypress

I’m rather new to buddypress and am getting a little bit confused. My setup is quite unusual in that I don’t need several of the buddypress components such as ‘activity’ or ‘friends’.

Instead I need the template to display several custom built web applications that Ihave coded myself.

Therefore to make life easy I edited the php templates in my themes /members/single/ directory. the files activity.php and friends.php respectively, to show my web apps.

I then created a bp-custom.php file and redifined the SLUGS to match the names of my web apps. i.e.

```
define( ‘BP_FRIENDS_SLUG’, ‘photos’ );
define( ‘BP_ACTIVITY_SLUG’, ‘songs’ );
define( ‘BP_GROUPS_SLUG’, ‘songsearch’ );
```

This worked great, when I clicked on the photos link, I was taken to my web app for photos etc… when i click songs it loads the activity template which contains my songs web app etc… etc….

However, now I need to add in more of my custom coded apps but have run out of these subcomponents to ‘butcher’ so my question is…. How do I add a new one?

I have created the file songprofile.php in the /members/single/ folder.

what I want is when the URL is http://www.mysite.com/members/user/songprofile/ for this songprofile.php template to be rendered within the members component in exactly the same way as my modified activity/friends templates are.

But i genuinely haven’t got a clue as to how I go about adding templates to the members component.

Obviously I still want the members-header.php to be loaded etc… everything the same, but just this new custom template to be rendered if that makes sense

Can anyone help?